Wrapping JUnit 5 extension to extract common code
I'm trying to figure out how to improve my test preparation code. I see lots of extension init code repeatedly, for example initializing system properties and environment variables using the SystemStubs extension. Below is a simplified snippet of what I'm trying to do. But it does not work. I'm trying to figure out whether wrapping of extensions is intended by the JUnit 5 creators or that (oh horror) I should inherit from SystemStubsExtension. Since lateron I would also like to include @Testcontainers in this extension to make sure I have a "prepare for end to end test" extension I'm trying to avoid inheritance. Are there any pointers? Is there a bit of documentation I missed or misunderstood?
@ExtendWith(SystemStubsExtension.class)
public final class CommonPropertySetExtension implements Extension {
    @SystemStub
    private SystemProperties systemProperties = new SystemProperties("prop1", "test");
}


You can write a JUnit extension - (e.g EnvInitializerExt) that implements JUnits callbacks as needed (BeforeAllCallback, AfterAllCallback, BeforeEachCallback, AfterEachCallback, ParameterResolver)
You could then use that jar in your pom.xml or gradle file, and register it in your tests and it will run your callbacks on each test run.
@RegisterExtension
private static final EnvInitializerExt envInitializer = new EnvInitializerExt(config);


This reply does not handle the issue of wrapping another extension.
